# What is the correct way to request a tag be added?

Tags: support, tags

I'm looking to add a tag for a new engine/game/sandbox experience called Resonite. This platform has scripting which is done in-game using a node based language, the experience revolves around collaborating and socializing while still focusing heavily on the development side of asset creation.

I'm not sure where to go to ask about adding a tag as it appears to be different for each stack exchange. Any guidance here would be immensely helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post a question that's relevant to the new tag. If we get enough questions about a topic, we'll add a tag for it.

An engine-specific tag is not a prerequisite before posting the question (since we handle lots of questions that aren't about game engines at all). You can use any other tags related to the problem you're asking about to appease the system and let you post.

If you find no relevant tags exist yet, you can choose a generic tag, then ask here or in chat for someone with sufficient rep to correct the tagging.